# Using the jQuery EmbedPicasaGallery plugin, how do I get the album description?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, picasa

I'm using the [jQuery EmbedPicasaGallery](http://oss.oetiker.ch/jquery/jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery.html) plugin on my website. Everything is working fine, except I need the ALBUM DESCRIPTION and this plugin gets the TITLE, but not the DESCRIPTION.

I don't know how to configure the plugin to label the albums with the album description, and
I'm not a programmer so I'm not sure how to change the code if that is what is needed.

I really hope you can help me with an example configuration or something like that.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the JQuery EmbedPicasaGallery plugin natively supports putting the Picasa album description under the album image at this time.

However, if you are using the most recent version (1.0.474), and you make a local copy you can adjust the code as follows to do what you need:

---

**First**: Patch jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery.js with these changes:

```
--- jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery.js    2011-08-31 10:48:22.424194969 -0400
+++ jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery.new.js    2011-09-13 20:40:34.785261085 -0400
@@ -103,6 +103,14 @@
             opts // add options
         );

+        function callbackWithInfo(opts,callback,idx,info) {
+            if (opts[callback] &&
+                $.isArray(opts[callback]) &&
+                $.isFunction(opts[callback][idx])) {
+              opts[callback][idx](info);
+            }
+        }
+
         function showOverview() {
             var $this,
                 meta_opts,
@@ -129,8 +137,9 @@


             function appendImage(i,item){
-                var title,$div,$img;
+                var title,$div,$img,desc;
                 title = item.media$group.media$title.$t;
+                desc = item.media$group.media$description.$t;
                 if (title.match(meta_opts.matcher)){
                     albumCount++;
                     $img = $('<img/>')
@@ -145,11 +154,22 @@
                         })
                         .click(function () {
                            $album_list.hide();
-                           showAlbum($this,meta_opts,item.gphoto$id.$t,title,item.gphoto$numphotos.$t);
+                           showAlbum($this,meta_opts,item.gphoto$id.$t,title,item.gphoto$numphotos.$t,desc);
                         })
                         .hover(
-                            function () { $(this).css("cursor","pointer")},
-                            function () { $(this).css("cursor","default")}
+                            function () {
+                                $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
+                                callbackWithInfo(meta_opts,'album_hover',0, {
+                                    title: title,
+                                    photoCount: item.gphoto$numphotos.$t,
+                                    description: desc
+                                });
+                                $(this).css("cursor","pointer")
+                            },
+                            function () {
+                                $(this).css("cursor","default");
+                                callbackWithInfo(meta_opts,'album_hover',1,{});
+                            }
                         )
                         .append( $img )
                         .append(
@@ -209,10 +229,16 @@
                     + '&alt=json-in-script&thumbsize=' + meta_opts.size + 'c&callback=?',
                     renderAlbumList
                );
-           }
+            }
         };

-        function showAlbum($this,meta_opts,album,title,photoCount){
+        function showAlbum($this,meta_opts,album,title,photoCount,desc){
+            callbackWithInfo(meta_opts,'album_toggle',0,{
+                title: title,
+                photoCount: photoCount,
+                description: desc
+            });
+
             if ( Cache[album] ){
                Cache[album].show();
                return;
@@ -266,7 +292,10 @@

             if (Cache.__overview && !meta_opts.hide_back){
                 $album.append(makeButton(meta_opts.msg_back)
-                    .click(function(){$album.hide();showOverview()})
+                    .click(function(){
+                        callbackWithInfo(meta_opts,'album_toggle',1,{});
+                        $album.hide();
+                        showOverview()})
                 );
             }
             $this.prepend($album);
```

This adds two new options to the jQuery.EmbedPicasaGallery.js plugin:

**`album_toggle`**

- An array of two functions to act as callbacks when an album is opened and closed.
- Active when a user selects an album from the album list.
- The first function is called on album open with the album information.
- The first function is passed an object with the following properties:

  - `title`
  - `photoCount`
  - `description`
- The second function is called on an album close.

**`album_hover`**

- An array of two functions to act as callbacks when an album is hovered over.
- Active when a user is hovering the mouse over an album in the album list.
- The first function is called when the mouse is hovering over the album image.
- The first function is passed an object with the following properties:

  - `title`
  - `photoCount`
  - `description`
- The second function is called when the mouse stops hovering over the album image.

**Next**: Initialize the jquery.EmbedPicasaGallery plugin and provide an implementation for each of these callback function options in order to update your info div with the album information.

Here is an example:

```
 $(function (){
    var $info = $('#info');

    function showInfo(info) {
        $info.html(info.title + " (" + info.photoCount + " photos) " + info.description).fadeIn('slow');
    }

    function hideInfo() {
        $info.hide().empty();
    }

    //This is the code you would change to use your own gallery,
    //instead of this random public one, see note below.

    jQuery("#pics").EmbedPicasaGallery('104892222647195875709', {
        matcher: /(neko\/lepestok_sakuri|нэко \/ котята)/,
        show_more: 20,
        loading_animation: 'css/loading.gif',
        album_title_tag: '<h3/>',
        album_hover: [showInfo,hideInfo],
        album_toggle: [showInfo,hideInfo]
    });
});
```

I've posted a working example at this [jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/mwolfetech/T6R7z/).  In it you will see the patched code for jQuery.EmbedPicasaGallery.js, followed by initialization code (you will need to scroll the javascript section to see the initialization code).  The initialization code is using a public gallery in which two of the albums had descriptions (This is not my gallery, but one I found on the featured pictures page).  If you select an album, the album should display with 15 pictures and the description under the pictures.

**Note:**

At the bottom of the JavaScript panel in the jsfiddle, if you scroll down, you will see this code:

```
jQuery("#pics").EmbedPicasaGallery('910489222264719587570', {
    matcher: /(neko\/lepestok_sakuri|нэко \/ котята)/,
    show_more: 20,
    loading_animation: 'css/loading.gif',
    album_title_tag: '<h3/>',
    album_hover: [showInfo,hideInfo],
    album_toggle: [showInfo,hideInfo]
});
```

If you replace `104892222647195875709` with your picasa userid, and remove the matcher line, you should see your public Picasa galleries after you click the **Run** button.

For example, if your Picasa userid is **fecapeluda**:

```
jQuery("#pics").EmbedPicasaGallery('fecapeluda', {
    show_more: 20,
    loading_animation: 'css/loading.gif',
    album_title_tag: '<h3/>',
    album_hover: [showInfo,hideInfo],
    album_toggle: [showInfo,hideInfo]
});
```

Additionally, I've provided the patched code as a GitHub [gist](https://gist.github.com/1215580).

Comment: thanks mwolfetech im gonna make a test and ill let you know whats happens, summary is used by picassa too i make a test with plain php and it work but not with ajax :/ So thanks illl be right back!

Comment: mwolfetech thats really works!!! But i need that when i make click in a album this show the contained photos and the container album description [here a link to see the idea](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/9071/demopageforembedpicasag.png).

Comment: @fecapeluda -- I've updated my answer.  I did not add a div with an id of info, instead, I added a div with a class of album-description-info

Comment: mwolfetech sir: thanks again for your help sorry say this but i couldn't make it work :/. I dont really know whats wrong i follow your example and all that.

Comment: @fecapeluda I've posted a working example of my code at jsfiddle, and I've edited my answer to explain how to use it to test my code.  I'm not sure if my code is exactly what you are looking for, as there are many ways you could fetch the description and use it, but out of the box jQuery.EmbedPicasaAlbum does not support it, so the true answer to your question is that you'd need to program it in--it is not supported out of the box.

Comment: mwolfetech sir: like always awesome!!!! that really works!!! I give for solved this problem but This is the [link](http://img838.imageshack.us/img838/8562/testgs.png) to see my NEW problem and the last thing that i wanna bother you. I really need to show the album description inside a custom Div (#info is css fixed and other times not) but i cant pass the album description value directly to this div  :/. Thanks again for your time and patience.

Comment: I may be able to pass a function you provide the description when the plugin has it.  I will look into this when I have time.

Comment: mwolfetech Thanks a lot sir! ill be waiting for your reply if you could set a jsfiddle demo ill really preciated. Cheers.

Comment: @fecapeluda  I've edited my post again, with the new implementation.  I hope it works for you or you can glean enough information from the examples I've given to do what you need.